# export from .shp to .gpx and .kml fails

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, export, gpx

I've just upgraded to QGIS Dufour and I am having some problems with the exportation of a simple track from .shp to .gpx and .kml format.
I imported from mi smartphone a .gpx track (SR WGS84 EPSG:4326), i converted it into .shp (EPSG:3857 in order to have it correctly projected over the google maps layer); I modified it and I finally need it to be exported into .gpx and .kml formats.

For .gpx: I did the "Save as", chose GPX format, set the RS to EPSG:4326, wrote "GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES" in the Data Source field and "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES" in the Layer field. Qgis says it all went ok (and it loads the track in the viewer and it looks fine), but when I load the .gpx track into my gps device I only see a straight line into the sea.
For .kml: I did the "Save as", chose KML format, set the RS to EPSG:4326. Qgis says it all went ok, but when I load it in the viewer it looks just empty and in google earth I can see a huge red cross over Africa... and I was looking for a road in Sardinia. 
Can anyone help me, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you add the gpx or kml to the canvas again, what extent is reported by Rightclick->Properties, Metadata tab?

Comment: The extension of the gpx layer is correct, while the one of the kml is blank.

Comment: Can you try with `Surpress Attribute Creation`? Maybe the GPS device does not like the extensions.

Comment: Where should I find that option?

Comment: In the `Save As...`Dialogue. In Englsh locale it is `skip attribute creation`.